# Cassandra Authentication issue

Tags: cassandra

cassandra version :apache-cassandra-2.1.8

I have recently configured 2 node cluster with `Authenticator`  set to `PasswordAuthenticator`. When one of the node is down I am not able to login to Cqlsh and gets below error

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', 
{'192.168.0.45': AuthenticationFailed(u'Failed to authenticate to 192.168.0.45: code=0100 [Bad credentials] 
message="org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM"',)})
```

The system_auth RF is set to 2 as i have 2 nodes.

```
C:\apache-cassandra-2.1.8-bin\apache-cassandra-2.1.8\bin>nodetool status
Starting NodeTool
Datacenter: DC1
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.0.45  327.87 KB  256     ?       66a97a0a-d69c-4daf-b0f5-55cb8442d728  RAC1
UN  192.168.0.46  234.28 KB  256     ?       432031fc-eea3-4b02-8d79-f877bbd8afaf  RAC1


KeySpace RF

cassandra@cqlsh> select * from system.schema_keyspaces;

 keyspace_name | durable_writes | strategy_class                              | strategy_options
---------------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------
   system_auth |           True | org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy | {"replication_factor":"2"}
        system |           True |  org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy |                         {}
 system_traces |           True | org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy | {"replication_factor":"2"}

(3 rows)
```

I have attached the Cassandra File,cassandra.yaml and cassandra-topology.properties file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might have something to do with this:

"For most system_auth queries, Cassandra uses a consistency level of LOCAL_ONE and uses QUORUM for the default cassandrasuperuser;"

Are you trying to connect as user "cassandra"?  If so, that might be why it is trying to use consistency level quorum.  Since you only have two nodes, a quorum would be both nodes.

So try creating a different user per the instructions [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html).