# Cassandra Keyspace table access issue

Tags: cassandra

cassandra version :apache-cassandra-2.1.8

After creating a superuser and successfully login in using the same user i have created a key space as

```
sufian@cqlsh:dbs> CREATE KEYSPACE DBS WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy','dc1' : 2} AND DURABLE_WRITEs =TRUE
```

and created a table `emp` as

```
sufian@cqlsh:dbs> create table emp ( empid int,deptid int,first_name varchar,PRIMARY KEY (empid,deptid));
```

When i try to query the table i get below error:

```
sufian@cqlsh:dbs> select * from dbs.emp; 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\apache-cassandra-2.1.8-bin\apache-cassandra-2.1.8\bin\cqlsh",
line 1078, in perform_simple_statement rows = self.session.execute(statement, trace=self.tracing_enabled) File "C:\apache-cassandra-2.1.8-bin\apache-cassandra-2.1.8\bin..\lib\cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.6.0c2.post.zip\cassandra-driver-2.6.0c2.post\cassandra\cluster.py", 
line 1594, in execute result = future.result(timeout) File "C:\apache-cassandra-2.1.8-bin\apache-cassandra-2.1.8\bin..\lib\cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.6.0c2.post.zip\cassandra-driver-2.6.0c2.post\cassandra\cluster.py", 
line 3296, in result raise self._final_exception Unavailable: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Comment: How many nodes are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Data center names are case sensitive.

You've defined the keyspace to have two replicas in 'dc1', but in your original question your data center name is 'DC1' (i.e. uppercase).

Cassandra will allow you to create keyspaces and tables in data centers that don't yet exist, so try changing your keyspace to use 'DC1'.

Comment: After spending much time in reading and troubleshooting i felt something is wrong with my RF

{ 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy','dc1' : 2}
dc1:2 =local node +1  (this is what i understand)
I changed it to dc1:1 and everything started working ...Replication is running fine , data is transferring on node 2 and can be accessed.I am bit confused , is dc1:1 means local node + 1 or just one node, if its one node then why replication is working, if it translate into 2 node then why do i get the error "Cannot achieve consistency level ONE"...

Answer (score 0):

Your consistency level is set as `ONE`. This means that a write must be written to the commit log and memtable of at least one replica node.

You seem to have only one node up. Adding another node should fix the problem.

EDIT:

Your replication factor seems to be set as 2, which means there should be one primary node and two replicas, with a consistency of ONE. So you need three nodes, and reads/writes must happen in at least one of them for the query to be successful. The other two replicas will get the data eventually making the query eventually consistent

Comment: I have 2 nodes and both the nodes are up and running. To see the node config please refer to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635963/cassandra-authentication-issue/31639838#31639838"

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the responses.